# GTK showing widget

Tags: c++, gdb, gtk

I was writing an little board game which has to add and show an image on a button after clicking on it, and then calling back some other function to show an image on other buttons,but the program didn't run as I think,the widget didn't show until all those functions done.
Here is debug:

```
Breakpoint 1, GameControl::button_clicked (widget=0x80dad08, data=0x80563e0) at interface.cc:582
582 image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("arrow.bmp");
(gdb) step
583 gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (widget), image);
(gdb) step
584 gtk_widget_show (image);
(gdb) step
585 computer_move (widget, &control);
(gdb) step
GameControl::computer_move (widget=0x80dad08, data=0x80563e0) at interface.cc:520
520 computer_moving = true;
(gdb) break interface.cc:586
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804cdab: file interface.cc, line 586.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Breakpoint 2, GameControl::button_clicked (widget=0x80dad08, data=0x80563e0) at interface.cc:586
586 break;
(gdb) step
593 end_dialog ();
(gdb) next
595 }
(gdb) step
0xb7b1c243 in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOIDv () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOIDv,which has no line number information.
0xb7b33a29 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function g_signal_emit_valist,
which has no line number information.
0xb7b34453 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0

(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Thread 0xb6b86b40 (LWP 7820) exited]
[Thread 0xb61ffb40 (LWP 7821) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 7817) exited normally]
```

until the last continue command was executed, the widget shows, for somehow the widget didn't show when it went to "gtk_widget_show ()" , any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+, like most GUI toolkits, is event-driven.

You are supposed to return from your callbacks so the main event loop (`gtk_main()`) can process the next event, otherwise the whole program just freezes.

If you want to process some events half-way through your callback, you do so explicitly. Straight from the docs:

```
/* computation going on */

while (gtk_events_pending ())
    gtk_main_iteration ();

/* computation continued */
```